A movie about a child witnesses a murder
A movie about a child witnesses a murder but his mother testifies in his behalf.
There is a murderer who kills someone and a child is looking out of his window and witnesses the murder, then the murderer sees and kills the child's (auntie?).
The police have to put his family under protection, in a house filled with panic buttons with a family, the family go to the shop and the mum sees the murderer so she presses the panic button and the murderer runs away.
Then the police finds out that it was actually the child who witnessed the murder, not the mother and the mother wanted to protect her child from having to testifies so she switched his room and her room around. 
I think the murderer had ginger/strawberry blond curly hair. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Could it be "Witness" (1985) with Harrison Ford (the cop) and Kelly McGillis (Mother) ??? In this movie is about a detective protecting a young Amish boy who becomes a target after he witnesses a murder in Philadelphia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(1985_film)
